# How do I model composable stochastic processes in rust?

Tags: algorithm, random, rust, iterator, coroutine

I'm writing a family of [Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo) algorithms to use as inference methods for a program induction system by translating the MCMC algorithms [implemented here in C++](https://github.com/piantado/Fleet/tree/master/src/Inference) into rust.

The rough dynamic of MCMC is that we have some process which randomly moves around a space of objects and generates a stream of the objects which it discovers. The randomness is essential. Also, this stream never terminates (though you can stop taking objects from the stream). More complex forms of MCMC can be defined as compositions of this basic process.

**My question**: how do I translate these algorithms idiomatically? More specifically, how do I to think about this problem from a rustacean perspective? What are the right tools/techniques to bring to the job?

Here's what I've considered:

1. A direct translation seemed awkward, because the C++ code makes heavy use of callbacks, and that felt awkward given my limited rust knowledge. It seems more in keeping with other rust code I've read to just make a stream of samples lazily available to the user to use as they see fit.
2. I then thought that iterators might make sense, but:

- The objects I'm sampling are complex data structures representing mini DSLs. It'd be nice to make a reference available that can be cloned if the user decides it's a useful sample. It's my understanding that this is a known limitation for iterators given rust's memory model.
- These algorithms all need a source of randomness (i.e. `&mut R` where `R: Rng`), and access to a simple control structure for keeping track of various statistics. Baking these directly into whatever struct implements `Iterator` then means that I can't compose the algorithms in a way that would share the control structure or source of randomness, right?

3. Generators/Coroutines seem to solve these problem, but seem like a relatively fringe/new area of rust. I began to wonder if I was making things harder than they need to be.
4. I currently provide the struct for each algorithm with a function similar to the following, where `H` is a hypothesis and `C` is the control structure:

   ```rust
   impl<C, H> MCMCChain<C, H> {
       // ...
       pub fn next_sample<R: Rng>(&mut self, control: &mut C, rng: &mut R) -> Option<Self>
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Ideally, `next_sample` would return `Option<&H>`, but this is what I have working right now.

Comment: Kudos on a well written question that shows that you have researched the subject first. Unfortunately I feel that this question is too broad for StackOverflow, which is more for questions focused on a specific issue rather than questions about architecture. You would do better to ask on the [Rust user forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/) or the [Rust Discord](https://discord.com/invite/rust-lang) who welcome more open-ended discussions.

Comment: I would root for way of implementing `Iterator`, because you can implement the logic of keeping some samples easily, for example like this `mcmc.filter(|&heavy| heavy.field > 0.01).take(10)`

Comment: I don't quite understand why iterators don't fit the bill. Iterators can return references that can be cloned. I don't know exactly what limitation you are referring to. Moreover, you can parametrize your iterator type with the RNG type, so you still have composability. The only thing you can't do is using a different RNG in each iteration, but that doesn't sound particularly useful to me anyway.

Comment: @Jmb - thanks. I hadn't thought of the Rust user forum or Rust Discord. Those are great ideas.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - Maybe iterators do fit the bill. My iterator skills may just not be up to snuff, but the Rust user forum is probably a more appropriate place to get help with this.